# I have a JSON response and I'm stuck on using it

Tags: java, android, json

My json is:

```
{"status":"ok","result": 
{"provider":"instagram","title":"lovely_songs_14u","link": 
[{"link_name":"Download 
Video","video_link":"https:\/\/scontent.cdninstagram.com\/v\/t50.2886- 
16\/71650124_386743795596239_6119869649307488549_n.mp4?_nc_ht=scontent.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=111&oe=5D907D5B&oh=36ad5ad325cce7926307dfb730583b70"}]}}
```

Android Side:

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, hp,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        //hiding the progressbar after completion
                        Log.e("Response", response);

                        try {
                            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                            categoryGetSet temp;

                            JSONArray ja_video = obj.getJSONArray("link");
                            for (int i = 0; i < ja_video.length(); i++) {
                                temp = new categoryGetSet();
                                JSONObject jo_data = ja_video.getJSONObject(i);
                                String txt_title = jo_data.getString("title");
                                String txt_link_name = jo_data.getString("link_name");
                                String txt_image = jo_data.getString("img_link");
                                String txt_video = jo_data.getString("video_link");

                                temp.setTitle(txt_title);
                                temp.setLinkName(txt_link_name);
                                temp.setImage(txt_image);
                                temp.setVideo(txt_video);

                                categoryGetSets.add(temp);

                                Log.e("dwnld", txt_link_name);
                            }

                            Log.e("try", "try");

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Log.e("catch", "catch");

                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;
                        if (networkResponse != null) {
                            Log.e("Status code", String.valueOf(networkResponse.statusCode));
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(networkResponse.statusCode), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

But it goes everytime into catch case, please let me know where i am doing it wrong

Comment: What is the exception it gives in catch block???

Comment: 2019-09-27 15:00:47.992 7189-7189/com.insta.instadownloader E/Response: {"status":"ok","result":{"provider":"instagram","title":"broken_heart_motivation","link":[{"link_name":"Download Video","video_link":"https:\/\/scontent.cdninstagram.com\/v\/t50.2886-16\/72404469_138243740820672_6328497230832195357_n.mp4?_nc_ht=scontent.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=100&oe=5D904EA6&oh=7ad0e53c9bcddbf6b9314dceb8776495"}]}}
2019-09-27 15:00:47.999 7189-7189/com.insta.instadownloader E/catch: catch

Comment: org.json.JSONException: No value for title

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is valid.

Use below code to parse your JSON.

```
try {
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
    categoryGetSet temp;

    JSONObject resultObject = (JSONObject) obj.get("result");

    String txt_title = resultObject.getString("title");
    String txt_provider = resultObject.getString("provider");
    JSONArray ja_video = resultObject.getJSONArray("link");

    for (int i = 0; i < ja_video.length(); ++i) {
        temp = new categoryGetSet();
        JSONObject jo_data = ja_video.getJSONObject(i);
        String txt_link_name = jo_data.getString("link_name");
        String txt_video = jo_data.getString("video_link");

        temp.setTitle(txt_title);
        temp.setLinkName(txt_link_name);
        temp.setImage(txt_provider);
        temp.setVideo(txt_video);

        Log.e("jsonResponse: ", "txt_title" + txt_title);
        Log.e("jsonResponse: ", "txt_link_name" + txt_link_name);
        Log.e("jsonResponse: ", "txt_provider" + txt_provider);
        Log.e("jsonResponse: ", "txt_video" + txt_video);
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.e("catch", e.getLocalizedMessage());
}
```

Comment: Again it is going into catch block

Comment: 2019-09-27 15:00:47.992 7189-7189/com.insta.instadownloader E/Response: {"status":"ok","result":{"provider":"instagram","title":"broken_heart_motivation","link":[{"link_name":"Download Video","video_link":"https:\/\/scontent.cdninstagram.com\/v\/t50.2886-16\/72404469_138243740820672_6328497230832195357_n.mp4?_nc_ht=scontent.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=100&oe=5D904EA6&oh=7ad0e53c9bcddbf6b9314dceb8776495"}]}}


2019-09-27 15:00:47.999 7189-7189/com.insta.instadownloader E/catch: catch

Comment: `Log.e("catch", e.getLocalizedMessage());`

Use this above line in your catch block.

Comment: org.json.JSONException: No value for title

Comment: Thank you so much it is working now, i will check where the issue was, really thanks

Comment: You were not parsing the JSON correctly.
Basically, the exception you were getting was parsing of JSONArray and your were looking that Array in your Main JSONObject. Whereas, it was in result Object.
That's what is done in this above answer.

Answer (score 1):

Because link array is inside result object but you are trying to get from outer object.so you are getting exception.

Try to parse like this

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
JSONObject resultObj=obj.getJSONObject("result");
JSONArray ja_video = resultObj.getJSONArray("link");
```

Comment: Again it is going into catch block

Answer (score 1):

It's going in catch because you are trying to parse in the wrong way,
You need to pass every JSON object and array sequence by sequence, Bellow is your structure

> - Main Json Object
>
>   - result Object
>
>     - link Array
>
>       - Sub Object with Data

And another wrong thing is you are trying some key which is not exist

Try Bellow code it will help you

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, hp,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        //hiding the progressbar after completion
                        Log.e("Response", response);
                        try {
                            JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONObject resultObj=mainObject.getJSONObject("result");
                            JSONArray linkJsonArrya = resultObj.getJSONArray("link");
                            categoryGetSet temp;

                            for (int i = 0; i < linkJsonArrya.length(); i++) {
                                temp = new categoryGetSet();
                                JSONObject jo_data = linkJsonArrya.getJSONObject(i);

                                if(jo_data.has("title")){
                                    temp.setTitle(jo_data.getString("title"));    
                                }else {
                                    temp.setTitle(jo_data.getString(""));
                                }

                                if(jo_data.has("link_name")){
                                    temp.setLinkName(jo_data.getString("link_name"));
                                }else {
                                    temp.setLinkName(jo_data.getString(""));
                                }

                                if(jo_data.has("img_link")){
                                    temp.setImage(jo_data.getString("img_link"));
                                }else {
                                    temp.setImage(jo_data.getString(""));
                                }

                                if(jo_data.has("video_link")){
                                    temp.setVideo(jo_data.getString("video_link"));
                                }else {
                                    temp.setVideo(jo_data.getString(""));
                                }
                                categoryGetSets.add(temp);
                            }
                            Log.e("try", "try");

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Log.e("catch", "catch");

                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;
                        if (networkResponse != null) {
                            Log.e("Status code", String.valueOf(networkResponse.statusCode));
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(networkResponse.statusCode), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

Comment: Again it is going into catch block

Comment: Can you post your log?